# Trying to install Pyramid package with "python setup.py install" gives error searching for a package

Tags: python-2.7, pip, pyramid, setup.py

I'm working on a Pyramid project that has to be deployed in a Debian 7 server.

The Debian 7 server has the python version 2.7.3 as from the archives repositories.

After creating a virtual environment with `virtualenv` command the pip version installed in this virtualenv is 1.1.

First thing noted: I can't upgrade pip with `pip install --upgrade pip`. The version is not updated and remains in 1.1 version.

After installing the OS packages needed to install the project I ran `python setup.py install` but I get the error:

```
Searching for zipp==0.5
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/zipp/
Couldn't find index page for 'zipp' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/
No local packages or download links found for zipp==0.5
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('zipp==0.5')
```

So, the `python setup.py install` command could not recognize the `zipp` package.

I thought that this was related to the older version of pip (1.1). So I could update pip version successfully using the `index-url` option:

```
$ pip install --index-url https://pypi.python.org/simple --upgrade pip
```

That updated pip version from 1.1 to 20.3b1. Then I tried `python setup.py install` again, but the same error occurred.

What I could see is that, after updating pip version, the `zipp==0.5.0` package is installed if I ran `pip install zipp==0.5`.

I'm new to Pyramid and the package installing using the setup.py module. I'm not understanding why I can install the zipp package with `pip` and can't with `python setup.py install`.

I'm not putting the content of setup.py here because I think it's not a problem of the setup.py script. With more recent versions of python and pip in an Ubuntu 18.04 machine the `setup.py` works like a charm.

Someone could explain how to solve this issue?

Comment: Never ever use both `pip` and `python setup.py install` to install packages. Choose only one method and use it consistently. They are not compatible. `pip` is highly preferred. You should wipe it clean and start over. Next, must you use an obsolete and unsupported OS, Python, and packages? I strongly recommend using the latest OS, Python, and packages, then reviewing the excellent [upgrading guide for Pyramid](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/upgrading.html) to bring your app up to date. It will be more supportable and operable in the long run.

Comment: Thanks for the response, @StevePiercy. In my case I do have to use this legacies versions. That's my nightmare, hehe. Thanks for the link for upgrading Pyramid. This will be the next phase of the project. By now I have to be able to deploy it in this legacies versions.

Comment: You could install your project with `pip install -e .` from the same directory in which you `setup.py` resides on a clean machine. I would also suggest updating the Python to the latest 2.7.x, however that is managed on Debian 7.

Answer (score 1):

When you run `python setup.py install` directly, you are not using pip, so the version of pip you have installed is irrelevant. This command is antiquated, should not be used, etc, etc. The right answer is to use `pip install .` as a replacement for `python setup.py install` and to use `pip install -e .` as a replacement for `python setup.py develop`.

With respect to what you're seeing, when you run `python setup.py install` this using the version of `easy_install` bundled with `setuptools` to talk to PyPI and install dependencies. This should be avoided for a lot of reasons but just know that to override urls it uses they go in `~/.pydistutils.cfg` and have nothing to do with pip. HTTPS is one problem that you looked at, another is that old versions of Python do not have the right CA trust store, nor support the minimum required TLS 1.2 to handshake with PyPI. So expect lots of problems using old tools - at the very least try to use pip instead of easy_install.